# When does Git refresh the list of remote branches?

Tags: git, github, branch, remote-branch

Using `git branch --all` shows all *remote* and *local* branches. When does Git refresh this list?

On pull/push? And how do I refresh it using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633)?

Comment: As a note, `git ls-remote` might be interesting here.

Comment: Don't forget to use `git fetch` before `git branch --all`

Comment: `git pull --all --prune` does the trick for me

Answer (score 2058, accepted):

To update the local list of remote branches:

```
git remote update origin --prune
```

To show all local and remote branches that (local) Git knows about:

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: `git remote update origin --prune` is what I was looking for thx

Comment: On the difference between this answer, which uses `git remote update`, and the accepted answer, which uses `git fetch`, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856504/1175496)

Comment: this is the correct answer. `git fetch` did not remove my local cache of remote branches. Only `--prune` was able to clean it all up.

Comment: You can have git automatically do this with `git config remote.origin.prune true`

Comment: `git remote prune origin` has the same effect and you type less.

Comment: @Dvin the OP asked for a refresh of the list; `remote prune` only cleans up dead branches list, it does not get new branches added to remote

Comment: Why does `git remote update origin --prune` have to be run manually? It should be clever enough to do this by itself if you have, for instance, checked out master from the server and there's no other branches (because they just got merged).

Comment: was able to pull my upstream branches using `git remote update upstream --prune`

Comment: I have to run this script to sync local with remote. `git fetch -p && for branch in `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'`; do git branch -D $branch; done`

Comment: If using with tortoise git then, have an option for Git Sync -> Pull (as Remote Update)

Comment: Bless you @centralcmd. it's very rare indeed that you search for a problem and find in the first try the exact solution you needed.

Answer (score 77):

The OP did not ask for cleanup for all remotes, rather for all branches of default remote.

So `git fetch --prune` is what should be used.

Setting `git config remote.origin.prune true` makes `--prune` automatic. In that case just `git fetch` will also prune stale remote branches from the local copy. See also *[Automatic prune with Git fetch or pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull)*.

Note that this does not clean local branches that are no longer tracking a remote branch. See *[How to prune local tracking branches that do not exist on remote anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064613/how-to-prune-local-tracking-branches-that-do-not-exist-on-remote-anymore/54484443#54484443)* for that.

Comment: To make it a little shorter `git fetch -p`

Answer (score 36):

I believe that if you run `git branch --all` from Bash that the list of remote and local branches you see will reflect what your local Git "knows" about at the time you run the command.  Because your Git is always up to date with regard to the local branches in your system, the list of local branches will always be accurate.

However, for remote branches this need not be the case.  Your local Git only knows about remote branches which it has seen in the last fetch (or pull).  So it is possible that you might run `git branch --all` and *not* see a new remote branch which appeared *after* the last time you fetched or pulled.

To ensure that your local *and* remote branch list be up to date you can do a `git fetch` *before* running `git branch --all`.

For further information, the "remote" branches which appear when you run `git branch --all` are not really remote at all; they are actually local.  For example, suppose there be a branch on the remote called `feature` which you have pulled at least once into your local Git.  You will see `origin/feature` listed as a branch when you run `git branch --all`.  But this branch is actually a *local* Git branch.  When you do `git fetch origin`, this tracking branch gets updated with any new changes from the remote.  This is why your local state can get stale, because there may be new remote branches, or your tracking branches can become stale.

Comment: Yep, `git fetch` did it.

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't work for me, need add `--prune`. Btw, I'm not downvoter ;)

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't remove deleted remote branches. That's probably why some people downvoted

Comment: tl'dr not true: git remote update origin --prune

Answer (score 7):

Use `git fetch` to fetch all latest created branches.

Comment: `git fetch` did not change anything for me with git 2.17.1. Which version and options have you been using?

Comment: You need either `--prune` or `git config remote.NAME.prune true` for this to solve OP question

Answer (score 1):

I use

```bash
git fetch --all --prune --tags --prune-tags --progress
```

and add this to my run commands file (.zshrc or .bashrc) so I can quickly type `gitf` to trigger this command:

```bash
alias gitf='git fetch --all --prune --tags --prune-tags --progress'
```